# Cannot read property 'json' of undefined

Tags: mysql, node.js

why is it not getting result ? The sql query is simple and correct and works in mysql

```
const getDateBw = (InvoiceDate1, InvoiceDate2, err, req, res) => {
   let startDate = new Date(InvoiceDate1);
   let endDate = new Date(InvoiceDate2);
   let formattedDate1 = JSON.stringify(dateFormat(startDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"));
   let formattedDate2 = JSON.stringify(dateFormat(endDate, "yyyy-mm-dd"));
   console.log(formattedDate1);
   db.query(
     "SELECT * FROM dashboard WHERE Invoice_Date BETWEEN " +
       formattedDate1 +
       " " +
       "AND " +
       formattedDate2
   ).then(function (myTableRows) {
    res.json({
       myTableRows,
     });
   });
 };
 getDateBw("2009-05-21", "2021-01-01");
```

```
{"level":50,
"time":1598543997608,
"pid":10772,
"hostname":"Ghadi-Mdallal",
"stack":"TypeError: Cannot read property 'json' of undefined\n    at C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\Dashboard-V1\\empServer\\handlers\\user.controllers\\user.controllers.js:29:9\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)",
"type":"Error",
"msg":"Cannot read property 'json' of undefined"
}
```

Comment: your function call to getDateBw has only two parameters while in defination you are using err,res as well. Don't you think something is missing there ?

Comment: please check the value of res by consoling it because what its look like that the res is undefined (and the errors say that you are trying to access the json property from undefined value)

Comment: @VipulPatil then what shall i pass if res is being undefined? i logged it and it was undefined

Comment: @AliAsgherBadshah yes it is undefined , what must i do so that it would be defined?

Comment: @ghadiMdallal req and res are the parameters are used by express router so first visit that part from online tutorial e.g. var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router

router.get('/', function(req, res) { // call your function of query here 
    res.json({ message: 'hooray! welcome to our api!' });   
});

Comment: you may want to revisit the tutorial https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing "res" in getDateBw("2009-05-21", "2021-01-01");

How will res.json work inside? It will give "Cannot read property 'json' of undefined" error.

Comment: res is undefined if you don't pass it.

Comment: I have sent res as a param but yet still undefined

Comment: I have sent res as a param but yet still undefined

Comment: Inside which function are you calling getDateBw ? You need to pass the "res" that Express or Node.js or any other FW gives you. That "res" has the .json in it. Just passing any "res" won't work.